# Optimize SQL query that uses multiple SELECT statements and returns one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I have a query that uses multiple SELECT statements containing different WHERE clauses to return multiple columns that get a count of orders in different categories. I am currently using a cte to try and optimize it, but it is still running very slow. I'm thinking a temporary table may be a faster solution, but I am having trouble getting there:

Query:

```
DECLARE @User AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @User = 'test.user';

WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    o.db_OrderNo,
    o.db_Deferral,
    d.db_SeqNo,
    d.db_Task
FROM
    tblOrders o
    LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = o.db_Status
    LEFT JOIN tblUserProfile up on up.db_UserId = o.db_RTS
WHERE
    o.db_Deleted = 0
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND d.db_Task IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
    AND up.db_Email LIKE @User + '%'
)
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE db_Task = 1
  AND db_Deferral = 0) OrderInEvalCount,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE db_Task = 2
  AND db_Deferral = 0) OrderInDfcCount,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE db_Task IN (3, 4) 
    AND db_SeqNo NOT IN (37, 39)
    AND db_Deferral = 0) OrderWipCount,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
  FROM cte 
  WHERE db_Deferral != 0) OrderInPendedCount
```

Output:

```
OrderInEvalCount | OrderInDfcCount | OrderWipCount | OrderInPendedCount
       20                  34              9                  2
```

Temp Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempCounts ( OrderInEvalCount int, OrderInDfcCount int, OrderWipCount int, OrderInzPendedCount int);

// First column

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo)
  INTO //Not sure how to specify a column
  FROM tblOrders o
  WHERE db_Task = 1
  AND db_Deferral = 0
  AND o.db_Deleted = 0
  AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01'
  AND up.db_Email LIKE @User + '%'
```

I haven't used TEMP tables before, so this start may be a little off. Any other solution that you think could speed up the current query would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for the outer select:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN db_Task = 1 AND db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                       END)) as OrderInEvalCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN db_Task = 2 AND db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                       END)) as OrderInDfcCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN db_Task IN (3, 4) AND db_SeqNo NOT IN (37, 39) AND
                                 db_Deferral = 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                       END)) as OrderWipCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN db_Deferral <> 0 THEN db_OrderNo
                       END)) as OrderInPendedCount
FROM cte;
```

SQL Server handles CTEs in a particular way:  it inserts the definition of the CTE into the query in each place it sees it.  So, your version runs the code for the CTE four times.  Although SQL Server can then optimize the query, it doesn't recognize that four chunks are doing the same thing . . . and so it does much more work.

When a CTE is only referred to once in a query, then using a CTE has no impact on performance.

Comment: yea, that works too... didn't know you could drop expressions into count like that... learn something every day

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! And there is an extra parenthesis after `db_Deferral = 0` on the second `CASE`. I can't make a one character edit.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working on the query so that it can be grouped on `db_OrderNo` to drop the distinct.

Then your select clause can sum case statements across the entire body of distinct order numbers.

```
select sum(case when db_Task = 1 and db_Deferral = 0 then 1 else 0 end) OrderInEvalCount
     , sum(case when db_Task = 2 and db_Deferral = 0 then 1 else 0 end) OrderInDfcCount
     , sum(case when db_Task in (3, 4) and db_SeqNo not in (37, 39) and db_Deferral = 0 then 1 else 0 end) OrderWipCount
     , sum(case when db_Deferral != 0 then 1 else 0 end) OrderInPendedCount
```